# PowerShell script throwing syntax error

Tags: unix, powershell

I am running a PowerShell script as follows:

```psh
$url = "http://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/forecast/29.36,47.97?app_id=****&app_key=****";
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Method ="GET"
$req.ContentLength = 0
$req.Timeout = 600000
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($resp.GetResponseStream())
$reader.ReadToEnd() | Out-File weatherOutput.json
```

It's giving the following error:

```
run.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
run.sh: line 2: `$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Unix environment use [`wget`](http://man.cx/wget) or [`curl`](http://man.cx/curl).

```sh
url="http://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/forecast/29.36,47.97?app_id=****&app_key=****"
wget -O weatherOutput.json $url
```

If you want the data echoed to `STDOUT` just replace the filename with `-`. You may also want to add the parameter `-q` to suppress informational/progress output.

```
wget -qO - $url
```

Or use `curl`, which writes the data to `STDOUT` by default.

Comment: thank you Ansgar it worked i am getting it data in json format and it is saving it in seperate file. please tell me how can get same information in command line i mean the contents which are storing in json file i want it on command line. is there any way to get it done..??

Comment: What do you mean by "on the command line"? Do you want the data echoed to STDOUT?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to run a PowerShell script in UNIX considering the error starts with `run.sh`. Powershell code can only be run on Windows machines With PowerShell installed (built in from Win7+, separate install for xp and vista).

Try running your script like using this command on a Windows-machine:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\myscript.ps1"
```

Comment: thanks Frode F for your response. i am triying to get data in command line from website the above script works fine in windows i can get data in command line . can you please suggest how can do the same in UNIX .

Comment: This code *might* already even work in [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash)

Comment: @Suyog you use wget for get site like `wget --recursive http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: hi hidd3n when i run the command wget --recursive  http://api.weatherunlocked.com  i got error 403 forbidden